# here-api - calculateroute distance

Tags: here-api

I am new to here-api and have a question wrt distance as shown in the response to a calculateroute request. Having a sequence of 100 waypoints recorded by GPS device along a road (~ 20m apart) the distance in the summary tag of the response is very different from what I calculate when summing up the distances between waypoints involved. Also bringing the waypoint sequence to a map shows that the summed up value is close to reality. whats going wrong here?

When sending a request like this

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json
?app_id=<my_app_id>
&app_code=<my_app_code>
&wayPoint0=geo!45.008503,7.555000
&wayPoint1=geo!45.006691,7.554025
&wayPoint2=geo!45.006470,7.554040
&wayPoint3=geo!45.006290,7.554018
&wayPoint4=geo!45.006096,7.553948
&wayPoint5=geo!45.005875,7.553872
&wayPoint6=geo!45.005615,7.553765
&wayPoint7=geo!45.004444,7.553305
&wayPoint8=geo!45.004116,7.553172
&wayPoint9=geo!45.003792,7.553035
&wayPoint10=geo!45.003460,7.552888
&routeattributes=routeId,waypoints,shape
&mode=shortest;car;traffic:disabled&returnelevation=true
```

I get a response consisting of 11 waypoints and 78 shapepoints. Calculating the distance via waypoints (using Haversine formula) yields a value of ~ 600 meters which looks reasonable and can be verified when exporting the result to kml and put on a map. However the distance tag under the summary section reports a distance of 3000 meters. Also the summed distance over shape points is much too high (2900m).

Comment: You should show an example request so we can see what is going on. A minimal verifiable example would be perfect. Besides, the distance "as the crow flies" between every 20m GPS waypoint on a road will be different from the distance between the first and last waypoint, and different from the actual length of the road between those two waypoints.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your GPS probes are not exactly on the road and calculateroute will compute a complex result.
When having a list of GPS tracks, you should use instead Route Map Extension (RME) that will figure out the correct/most probable route.